# Can I use Relay against a GraphQL schema that doesn't implement the Node interface / unique IDs?

Tags: graphql, relay

The GraphQL schema doesn't implement the Node interface and the entities don't have a unique `id` property. Can Relay consume such schema? If it can, how it will be limited?